# Focused crawling from nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch 1.2 and solr 3.1.0 and a NUTCH-828-1-20100608 patch for fetch filter.

I don't understand how to filter the fetch, nor do I understand how the patch works. [This link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Focused-crawling-with-nutch-td3656343.html) helped me patch the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the wiki [0] first. There is a lot of documentation available and you can customize it based on your requirements.

[0] - http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FrontPage